# How to implement promises with the HTML5 Geolocation API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, geolocation

How could I correct the code below so that it does not return the `undefined` value for the `getPreciseLocation` function?

In summary, there should be an AJAX call to get the current weather when the user clicks the `#precise-location-prompt` and shares the location with the browser. However at the moment there is an `undefined` value error straight after the user clicks on the `#precise-location-prompt`.

```
// Get weather data for the current location
function getCurrentWeather(coordinates) {
  return $.ajax('http://www.example.com/lat=' + coordinates[0] + '&lon=' + coordinates[1]);
}

// Show weather in DOM
function showCurrentWeather(data) {
  var currentTemperature = data.temperature;
  $('#current-temperature').text(currentTemperature);
}

// Get precise location based via the Geolocation API
function getPreciseLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition, displayError);
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
  }
}

// Success function for the Geolocation API
function displayPosition(position) {
  return [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
}

// Error function for the Geolocation API
function displayError(error) {
  console.log('Precise location is not available at the moment.');
}

// Promises chain with the AJAX requests
function getWeatherWrapper() {
  return getPreciseLocation().then(function(locationData) {
    return getCurrentWeather(locationData);
    }).then(function(weatherData) {
      return showCurrentWeather(weatherData);
    });
}

// User's interaction with the website
$('#precise-location-prompt').on('click', getWeatherWrapper);
```

Comment: What is expected result if `displayError` is called?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This demo uses the JSfiddle AJAX methods (which, strangely, uses Mootools) to mock the request but you can substitute in the `$.ajax` method. I also substituted the rest of the jQuery for vanilla JS event listeners and selectors for this test, but you can add them back in for your code very easily.

Return a new promise which resolves in the `success` callback.

```
function getCurrentWeather(coordinates) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    new Request.JSON({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      data: {
        json: JSON.encode({ temperature: 'Too hot!' }),
        delay: 1
      },
      onSuccess: function (response) {
        resolve(response);
      }
    }).send();
  });
}

function showCurrentWeather(data) {
  var temp = document.getElementById('current-temperature');
  temp.textContent = data.temperature;
}
```

Return a promise that resolves when your original `displayPosition` was called. I added back that function back into `getPreciseLocation` because it was easier to get it working. You can also add back in your checks for geolocation here, and a `reject` as you see fit.

```
function getPreciseLocation() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      resolve([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
    });
  });
}
```

Here we just reduce the code footprint to call the relevant functions with the appropriate data.

```
function getWeatherWrapper() {
  getPreciseLocation()
    .then(getCurrentWeather)
    .then(showCurrentWeather);
}

var prompt = document.getElementById('precise-location-prompt');
prompt.addEventListener('click', getWeatherWrapper);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4a59k1tz/11/)