# Assigning map co ordinates in javascript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

```
(async ( ) =>  {
    async function foo() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)
        {
            var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
            };
            
            function success(pos) {
            var crd = pos.coords;
            console.log('Your current position is:');
            console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
            lat = crd.latitude;
            console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
            long = crd.longitude;
            console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
            return [lat, long];
            }
            
            function error(err) {
            console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
            }
        };
    };
})
    

let result = await foo();
console.log(result);

 x = await result[1]
    console.log(x);
```

I was trying to grab map  co-ordinates fom browser and assign them to variables so as to compare to other co-ordinates and find the proxmity to a place.
but it keeps returning un

Comment: Your code creates an `async =>` function but it doesn't call it.

Comment: Why are `options`, `success` and `error` wrapped in a block?

Comment: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `foo` doesn't return anything

Comment: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784) and [How to implement promises with the HTML5 Geolocation API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36996529/3082296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question where these "other" co-ordinates are coming from, whether they're hard-coded, or loaded from cookies, or localStorage, but this example gets the co-ordinates and saves them to an array which is then saved to localStorage which is loaded whenever the page is refreshed.

It uses one promise to return the results of the geolocation search, and one async method for the main function.

Note: due to security issues this won't run in a snippet, but it has been fully tested.

```js
const posArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pos')) || [];

function getPos(options)  {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (pos) => res(pos),
        (err) => rej(logError(err)),
        options
      );
    }
  });
}

function logPos(data) {
  const { accuracy, latitude, longitude } = data.coords;
  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${accuracy} meters.`);
  posArr.push({ accuracy, latitude, longitude });
  localStorage.setItem('pos', JSON.stringify(posArr));
}

function logError(err) {
  const { code, message } = err;
  console.error(`Error code ${code}: ${message}`);
}

const options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

async function main(options) {
  try {
    const response = await getPos(options);
    if (response) {
      logPos(response);
      console.log(posArr);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Position not available.');
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I would be hardcoding the other co-ordinates to another set of array.